# Change button text from "Like" to "Liked" when clicked

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating a forum where users are able to like and unlike posts and comments.
 The challenge I'm facing is that I would like the text of the like button to change without reloading the page. How can I go about differentiating between the buttons on the page and change individual button-texts from "Like" to "Liked" and vice versa? 
The buttons are, at the moment created and show like this:

```
<?php
$result3=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM cs_comments WHERE post_id = $postID");
while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)){
    $commentID=$row3['comment_id'];
    $memberID=$row3['member_id'];
    $likes=$row3['likes'];
    $content= $row3['content'];
    $anonymous=$row3['anonymous'];


    if($anonymous=='1')
        $name='Anonym';
    else{
        $result4= mysqli_query($link, "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM cs_members WHERE member_id = $memberID");
        $row4=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4);
        $name = '<a href="../profile/?profile=' . $memberID . '">' . $row4['firstname'] . " " . $row4['lastname'] . '</a>';
    }
    $result5=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM cs_likes WHERE comment_id=$commentID AND member_id={$_SESSION['memberID']}");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result5)!=0)
        $liked="unlike";
    else
        $liked="like";




    echo '<div class="post_container">';
    echo '      <div class="info_header">';
    echo '          <div class="info_name">' . $name . '</div>';
    echo '          <div class="info_group"></div>';
    echo '      </div>';
    echo '      <div class="post_content">';
    echo            $content;

    echo '      </div>';
    echo '      <div class="post_footer">';
    echo '          <div class="like_button"><button onclick="likeComment('. $commentID . ')">' . $liked . '(' . $likes . ')</button></div>';
    echo '      </div>';
    echo '</div>';
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Javascript for onclick-event:

```
function likeComment(id) {
$.ajax({
    url: '/resources/phpScript/like.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {comment_id:id},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data); // Inspect this in your console
    }
});
```

Like.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include "./db-connect.php";
$memberID= $_SESSION['memberID'];

if(isset($_POST['post_id'])){
    $postID=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['post_id']);
    $sqlCheck="SELECT * from cs_likes WHERE post_id = $postID AND member_id = $memberID";
    $sqlInsert="INSERT INTO cs_likes (post_id, member_id) VALUES ('$postID','$memberID')";
    $sqlDelete="DELETE FROM cs_likes WHERE post_id= $postID AND member_id = $memberID";
}
elseif(isset($_POST['comment_id'])){
    $commentID=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['comment_id']);
    $sqlCheck="SELECT * from cs_likes WHERE comment_id = $commentID AND member_id = $memberID";
    $sqlInsert="INSERT INTO cs_likes (comment_id, member_id) VALUES ('$commentID','$memberID')";
    $sqlDelete="DELETE FROM cs_likes WHERE comment_id= $commentID AND member_id = $memberID";
}
else
    echo "Something went wrong";
$checkResult=mysqli_query($link, $sqlCheck);
if(mysqli_num_rows($checkResult)==0)
    $result=mysqli_query($link,$sqlInsert);
else
    $result=mysqli_query($link,$sqlDelete);
?>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: so where's the js for this?

Comment: @Fred -ii-  So sorry! That was a mistake

Comment: you have `<button onclick="likeComment` so that's js. If you don't have any js for it, then are you asking us how to do an ajax call? If so, that's what you need here. If that isn't what you're asking, then what's not working? Quite a few unknowns here.

Comment: This should be achieved in the front end

Comment: Please share your html and javascript files, otherwise we can't really help you  ; )

Comment: @Fred -ii- Well, it works, but the text in the button will not change from "Like" to "Liked" unless the page is refreshed. I guess what I am asking is "How can I differentiate between the buttons on the page"?

Comment: Try a ternary operator instead or a conditional statement. Again, if it's a JS issue that isn't firing up an event, then you need to update your question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I will update my question with the js and like.php

Comment: @Webomatik done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution! I have little to no experience with javascript, which is why this may have been too simple of a question for anyone to find out what I was after!
This is what I did:

I simply sent the element clicked by adding `this` to the function call on click:

```
echo '          <div class="like_button"><button onclick="likePost('. $postID . ',this)">' . $liked . '</button></div>';
```

I then added this tiny bit to my function:

```
function likePost(id, elem) {
if(elem.innerHTML== "like")
    elem.innerHTML="unlike";
else
    elem.innerHTML="like";
```

I still want to thank everyone who made and effort to try understanding what I was asking.